# Trying to get BeautifulSoup to download some data. Getting no error, but nothing is downloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I just tried to run the code below.  I got no error message, but no data was actually written to the CSV.  I looked at the website and I found both `snapshot-td2-cp` and `snapshot-td2` elements.  When I remove the writer.writerow statements and use print statements, I see six number 2 characters, and that's it.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [url_base + s for s in tckr]

with open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/today.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = requests.get(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage.content, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```

In the SBUX example, I want to get data from this table.

[image]

I tested this code a few months ago, and everything worked fine.  Can someone point out my mistake?  I'm not seeing it.  Thanks.

Comment: You are getting a 403: Access Denied response on `fpage`.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out the same.  I don't recall having to login to that site anytime before.  So, I suppose I need Selenium for this?  Does that sound right?

Comment: yeah selenium is the path to automated browsing @ASH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data, specify `User-Agent` in your requests.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for t, url in url_list:
        print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
        writer.writerow([t])
        for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
            writer.writerow([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
```

Prints:

```
Scrapping ticker SBUX...
Scrapping ticker MSFT...
Scrapping ticker AAPL...
```

and saves `data.csv` (Screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]